# Extract dicom pixeldata and export to a textfile that can be read by a javascript?

Tags: javascript, dicom

Could someone please enlighten me on the easiest way (which free program?) to export pixeldata from a dicom file and make that data available for a javascript?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the free **[Daikon](https://github.com/rii-mango/Daikon)** parser which is written in JavaScript. This will allow you to read the dicom file directly in the browser (or via Node.js).

Just note that as calibration is not easy to perform in the browser it must not be used for medical purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a try to [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/), that is a DICOM server with a RESTful API. Its API notably allows the conversion of DICOM files to PNG images on-the-fly.